# How to use Manticore Regex using sphinxapi

Tags: php, search, sphinx, manticore-search, manticore

I am using sphinxapi adding queries using addQuery() but It does add everything inside MATCH("...") and in Manticore there is Regex functionality apart from Sphinx. Do you know how to use this regex on php and runQueries() get results.

Comment: Do you mean the REGEX() string function? Can use that in a SetSelect() expression. It's effectively the bit between SELECT ... FROM from SQL

Comment: For Example like this : 
SELECT name FROM story WHERE REGEX(name, '^GALL\\w{0,3}$')";
Would be same thing using SetSelect() with my query ? What I understand from your sentence it will consider Regex on selection process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you cant write it exactly like that in SQL, would be something like

```
SELECT id,name,REGEX(name, '^GALL\\w{0,3}$') AS filter FROM story WHERE filter=1;
```

So to translate that into the API

```
$cl->setSelect("name,REGEX(name, '^GALL\\w{0,3}$') AS filter");
$cl->setFilter('filter', array(1));
$r = $cl->Query('', 'myindex');
```

Basically have to create a virtual attribute as result of expression. Then filter by that. Not something can do in most actaul RDMS, but its how it done in sphinx/manticoew. `filter` is just an arbitary name I chose.

Comment: Very very thanks. It is so logical. I will check it asap. 

Also I am using php5.6 and I connected via mysql from php but when I try to use REGEX It just gives me one result despite of using while operator to get all results. Also tried to limit it so I can get many results. Without REGEX it is okay I can get all results I want

Comment: Honestly that sounds like possible encoding issue. The regular expression will need encoding as in SQL encoded. But also encoding if written in PHP string for example

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working. You saved my day